# I want to use JQuery to Hide header row if the non-header row is only one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use JQuery to Hide header row if the non-header row is only one.
And keep the header visible if there are multiple non-header rows after the header row.
i.e.

```html
<tr class="header head1"></tr>
<tr class="non-header"></tr>
<tr class="non-header"></tr>
<tr class="header head2"></tr>
<tr class="non-header"></tr>
<tr class="header head3"></tr>
<tr class="non-header"></tr>
<tr class="non-header"></tr>
```

So I want to hide head2 because after that there is only one non-header row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `.filter()` method to filter the `.header` elements based on whether there are more than two `.non-header` siblings elements *until* the next `.header` element.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/0pfxsj83/)

```
$('.header').filter(function () {
  return $(this).nextUntil('.header').length < 2;
}).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr.header + tr.non-header + tr.header').prev().prev().hide();
```

Should get you there.

Also I don't think you have to make all your non-header rows of class non-header just for this. You could also just go with

```
$('tr.header + tr:not(.header) + tr.header').prev().prev().hide();
```